# Do Workflow actions execute in a certain order or all at once?

Tags: workflow, workflowoutboundmessage, order, order-of-execution

Do the following actions occur in a certain order, or do they all fire off at the same time?

- Email Alerts
- Tasks
- Field Updates
- Outbound Messages

Answer (score 7):

From SF documentation:

> The order in which individual actions and types of actions are executed is not guaranteed. However, field update actions are executed first, followed by other actions.

http://na6.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/workflow_rules_considerations.htm

So basically, you can be assured that the field updates will occur first, but the order of the remaining actions is random and undefined.

Comment: Is it the case that even though they happen in an unpredictable order, they still happen sequentially, ie not all at the same time? I'm not sure what use that information is given that the order is unpredictable after field updates are completed, but I'm interested nevertheless.